# PostgreSQL select from 3 many-to-many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, many-to-many

I'm using PostgreSQL, and I've got the following tables:

1. Category
2. Service
3. Report

All of them have many to many relationships to each other, so I've got the following tables for relationships between them:

4. link_category_service
5. link_category_report
6. link_service_report

I got stuck with the SQL query that allows getting all the categories-reports ids for the particular service with some id (for service with id 4, for instance):

category_id | report_id

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Are reports related to categories or to services? Sample data and desired results would make your question easier to understand.

Comment: reports are related both to categories and services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a direct link between `category` and `report` - you can query the mapping table, and filter according to the link tables with the `service` table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   link_category_report
WHERE  category_id IN (SELECT category_id
                       FROM   link_category_service
                       WHERE  service_id = 4) AND
       report_id IN (SELECT report_id
                     FROM   link_report_service
                     WHERE  service_id = 4)
```

Comment: However, I checked now and there's one another problem with this query: If service has category , but does not have any report of this category, I would like to return categoryId and null value for corresponding reportId. How do I do that?